# Is storing raw data with the result object bad practice?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a class that is already very long and that I'd like to split. At one point I do a lot of calculations (based on two integer and two Lists) and store the results into a result object.
My idea was to pass the integers and Lists to the "result object", do the calculations inside its constructor and assign the results to its instance variables (I would pass the result object in a subsequent step). This way I keep the code that is just a means to an end (needed only once to do the calculations) at the place where the result is stored. 
This also keeps methods and data together at one place instead of two, which increases modularity. It leaves me with one class that has it all: the raw data, the algorithms and the results. I just need to assure to pass the parameters to the constructor.

Yet my gut feeling tells me that this is a design flaw. So, is storing raw data with the "result" object bad practice? Should I make the calculations inside the object or outside and simply use it as a DTO?

Comment: Instantiating an object is always a time and resource consuming task in Java, so would not place any processing into a constructor...

Comment: why not? it saves CPU power. If the calculation is complicated and takes minutes or hours to be done, then you'll store raw and result together without thinking. Make sure you'll re-calculate the results if the raw data is changed.

Comment: Well actually i do not store the raw data, but the reference to it/the lists. Why are calculations in constructor slower, doesn't make sense to me. I'd need the data anyway, so why not passing everything to the constructor. This provides me with a ready-to-use object at runtime and keeps all related data together at compile time.

Comment: Perform the calculations outside of the constructor, then create the object once the calculations have been performed, "[injecting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)" the results via the constructor. Constructors typically only contain assignments. You can hide the calculations via a static factory method.

Comment: A design is good or bad depending on your use case. Do you need to cache the results? Will you get the same input parameters often enough or are they always different? Do you need to preform many of these calculations concurrently?

Comment: I don't necessarily think it's bad practice, it sounds like a form of [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).  I wonder how you will know that a particular set of the integers and lists are a match for one of your previously-computed result objects?  Would you need to explicitly compare the integers and lists against all of your result objects to identify a hit?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is some way to save some CPU cycles by storing a previously performed calculation and I think that's a good thing. I would stay away from doing that in the constructor, an alternate approach I would suggest is to have a private variable hold the result (C# code below)

```
public class MyCoolClass
{
   private int? _myPreviousResult = null;

   public int GetMyCalculationResult()
   {
       if (_myPreviousResult != null)
       {
           return _myPreviousResult;
       }
       // do the long calculation here
       // ...


       _myPreviousResult = result;
       return _myPreviousResult;
   }
}
```

Set _myPreviousResult to null if any of the variables in play for calculation changes.